# Find best combination with Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am developing a deck combination optimizer for a card game with machine learning. The idea is to first collect the historcal battle records. Then use the data the predict the best deck combination.

For example, if we have a record of

```
deck_1 = [card_1, card_2, card_3]
deck_2 = [card_4, card_5, card_6]
```

if deck_1 wins, the score of deck_1 = 1, deck_2 = 0
Using this data we can create a table

```
| card1    | card2    | card3    | score   |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |-------- |
| card_1   | card_2   | card_3   | 1       |
| card_4   | card_5   | card_6   | 0       |
```

Assuming the number of card is at a range of 1 to 3 so I make 3 static fields for cards

A possible solution for the predicting model is to subsitute all combination of card to predict a score, and get the max E.g.

```
maxOf (
predict(card_1, card_2, card_3) 
predict(card_1, card_2, card_4) 
predict(card_1, card_2, card_5)
...
predict(card_4, card_5, card_6) 
)
```

But the problem is, if there are 100 cards, I need to predict 970200 combinations. Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

Does the position of the card in your deck matter? Is deck1 = c1,c2,c3 different then deck2 = c2,c3,c1? If not, you only need 100C3 = 161,700 deck combinations. This is already an improvement.

The best deck combination at a given time will be from a subset of all available cards. If all cards are available, there is no prediction; you objectively know which deck is the most powerful. E.g. you are given a subset of 20 cards, and then you get the best possible deck from this. A player will not have access to all 100 cards at all times. If that was the case, every player will have the same deck.

A naive solution will be to assign each card its own rank, equal to the number of times that particular card was part of a winning deck. Then from your available cards, select the top 3 as part of your deck.

Depending on the game, you'll want to account for synergy between cards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling). As an example, you could use a neural network (or any other ML method) to predict the probability for a deck to win, using the historical data. You can then use importance sampling (e.g. [Cross-entropy method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy_method)) to sample from the pool of cards to assemble your deck. The predictions from the NN would serve as the objective for the importance sampling.

This would not require you to check over all possible combinations of cards, but would optimize the card sampling using the predictions from the neural network.